# Multi-records Custom Field

Tags: profile, multi-record

i have a simple Custom Field set that has 2 text field to capture "Year" and "Class".  This custom field is set to keep multiple records/values.  The idea is to track the person's class information over years.

It seems that I can do a batch update of this custom field through a profile, but instead of updating the existing records, it goes ahead and add new records/value.

Just to confirm that this is the behavior for batch-update of custom field with multiple records, and currently the interface does not allow batch-update of existing values.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating a contact via profile with multivalue custom field will always create new entry for those custom set. The only way you can update is using the contact edit form.

Cheerz

Pradeep